# Alfresco - Want to Change Content store path

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I want to change the existing content store path of my Alfresco instance just because it is about to get full. One solution is to move existing content store at another location and change the path in alfresco.global.properties but I want to write new data at another location and read the existing from the current one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't edit the "dir root" property because that folder contains files needed for a proper Alfresco boot up. However, you can use the Alfresco "content store" feature to simply add any number of additional stores.

Read up on content stores.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/store-manage-content.html

http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/concepts/store-config-fullexample.html

I just now see that Krutik used the same links as I did, sorry about that. If you're using CE you can still use/add your own content stores. The feature missing is the OOTB "content store selector" where you would choose the concrete content store by setting a property/aspect on a specific node.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, it will be kind of impossible thing in alfresco.First reason would be as below.

- Dir Root is having indexes of files.If we devide it, for solr it will be diffucult to manage this things.

There are lot more other reasons as well.

But for solving this in future you can set up content store configuration.You will find details about that in below link.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/manage-cs-home.html

Specially below one will be more usefull.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/store-config-fullexample.html

This is available in enterprise version.I don't know 100% about content store, reading full documentation will might solve your problem.

Comment: Do you have any idea about this . https://github.com/AFaust/simple-content-stores

Comment: not much......but basically i think its using the same things internally.

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is possible but maybe not as you expect. AFaust's simple-content-stores is a collection of different content store implementations following different concepts how to generate the server side document path. You may check the [selector property-based routing store](https://github.com/AFaust/simple-content-stores/wiki/Selector-Property-Store) to chose the location by creation/modification date.
If your goal is just to handle your restricted disk space in a test and development system it may be much easier to work with symlinks (or shortcuts) by moving folders to another disk and create symlinks instead where Alfresco expects the directory.
But be warned: This may end up in a confusing folder structure. If you loose the overview about your moved folders you may accidently cause data loss.

If you you run on linux/unix it may be much easier to create logical volumes containing different physical devices/partitions.

Another quite simple solution: move the whole directory alf_data/contentstore/ to a network storage, big enough to store all the data and change that path in your alfresco-global.properties